# Convoluting a rank 4 tensor over only one dimension

Tags: tensorflow

I have a rank 4 tensor (stimulus, balance, disturbance, and time), and I'd like to convolute *only* across the last dimension (i.e. time).  How can I do this using `conv1d` in TensorFlow?

Comment: How about (1) tf.reshape to a a 1d tensor, (2) tf.split to stimulus x balance x disturbance 1d tensors, (3) conv1d, (4) tf.concat, and (5) tf.reshape back to the 4d tensor?

Comment: @YaoZhang This sounds like a good approach, but is easier said than done.  There's lots of challenge in the details.

Comment: Hmm, this might be a simpler solution: (1) reshape to 1d, and (2) do conv1d across this 1d array, (3) throw array the invalid boundary values by using tf.select, and (4) reshape back to the 4d tensor with the new output shape.

Comment: @YaoZhang That won't work, because the conv1d will leak from the next disturbance since they're all next to each other

Comment: Not sure why you mean by "leak". Here is an example, say I want to compute convolution for three 1d arrays [a0,a1,a2,a3], [b0,b1,b2,b3], and [c0, c1, c2, c3] and my filter size is 3, so the final output are [x0, x1], [y0, y1], [z0, z1]. Now I concatenate them together do a single 1d conv over [a0,a1,a2,a3,b0, b1,b2,b3,c0,c1,c2,c3] and get [x0,x1,G,G,y0,y1,G,G,z0,z1], now I use tf.select to throw array the G(Garbage) values to get the final output.